# Is there a way to click on button in application using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

using powershell code i would like to open the application and click on any option. like open Notepad++  and click on file -->new

This is independent script which run in powershell console

i tried to grab the Notepad++ window handle like this

```
$WindowHandle = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -Match $WindowTitle } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle
```

but i am not able to click on it.

to open Notepad++

```
start-process "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

to grab the window

```
 $WindowHandle = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -Match $WindowTitle } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle
```

any code snippet which can help me in grabbing the control on notepad++ and click on options or buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the actions you want to do have a shortcut, you could just send the keys to the window.

For example to open a new file you can use `CTRL + N`

```
start-process "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
$WindowHandle = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -Match $WindowTitle } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{n}")
```

EDIT:
When you press `ALT` in Notepad++ it will show you the shortcuts you can use to open the different menus.

[image]

To open `File`, you can use `ALT+F` (The F is underlined, meaning that's the shortcut).
After that you could navigate down/up using keys to select what you want. Most applications will have this behavior.

Besides that, in Notepad++ you could also map pretty much any action to a key combination. However, this would mean your script only works on your PC, with your settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. I need one help..if its not with ctrl + n  if i want to click on any button in application is that possible.?

Comment: When you press the `ALT` key in notepad++ it will show shortcuts for all the menu tabs. Most applications have this enabled (or should have :) ). I'll edit my answer with what I mean.

Comment: what's the mechanism by which `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{n}")` knows to send that key to the `$WindowHandle` window? Is it looking for a variable in the local environment explicitly named `$WindowHandle`?