# Is it possible to click a button in an application using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

i am trying to write a powershell script that checks connectivity thru a continuous ping, if the ping is unsuccessful the script should start a process and when a window is opened have the script click on a  specific button, i have done my research and have not found much help other than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076058/is-there-a-way-to-click-on-button-in-application-using-powershell)

but this is dependant on Actions having schortcuts that's why it doesn't work for me, i would like to know if it's even possible to do this using powershell before i procced with my work.
this is my script so far.

```
$IP = "192.X.X.X"
$TimeOut = 500
$FailureThreshold = 10
$Ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

Do {
$Result = $Ping.Send($IP,$Timeout)
if ($Result.Status -eq "Success") {
    Write-Output "Working as intended."
    Exit 0
}
else {
    Write-Output "Ping Failed!"
    $Failures += 1
}
} until ($Failures -ge $FailureThreshold)
Write-Output "Main DHCP is Down, Starting Backup DHCP Server..."

start-process   "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\DHCP\dhcpsrv2.5.2\dhcpsrv.exe"
```

everything works great, i just need to get that button clicked.
and here is a photo of the window that pops up and the button that needs to be clicked.
[image]

Comment: not easily, not directly. however, PoSh can use AutoIT with the module for that tech and _then_ click UI objects.

Comment: The underlined letter indicates the key combo Alt + C will press that button. So you could try to send those key presses.

Comment: @DougMaurer, i had no idea! thanks a lot!

Comment: A better solution is to install that as a service and then you don't have to click on anything. Just set the service to automatically start.

Comment: Based on comments on the answer, my guess is that this question is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I think you need to explain the actual _problem_ and not your attempted _solution_.

Comment: No need to get all haughty, Bill Stewart.  One of the first rules of Stack Overflow is 'be nice'.

Comment: 1) How are my responses not "nice"? 2) "Accuracy" > "niceness" from a technical perspective. Not that "nice" isn't important, but it's arguably more important to be correct and accurate when delivering technical guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got it! Maybe this will help someone.

```
start-process   "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\DHCP\dhcpsrv2.5.2\dhcpsrv.exe"
$StartDHCP = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
Sleep 1
$StartDHCP.SendKeys('%C')
```

where % = ALT

Comment: I don't recommend the SendKeys method for production use because it depends heavily on window focus (if the window you're expecting doesn't have focus when you are expecting, this won't work).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart well in this situation the window does have focus so SendKeys is getting the job done, which is what i was looking for.

Comment: The point is that you don't really have control over which windows has focus (you put a sleep, but that doesn't guarantee anything). A better solution is to install this DHCP tool as a service that starts automatically (see your screen shot), and then you don't have to worry about starting it manually, sending a keystroke to the window, etc.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart i see, so if i install it as a service will i still be able to have it automaticcaly activated only after the main DHCP is down in the same way with powershell?

Comment: What do you mean by "main DHCP is down"? It sounds like you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: sorry i thought i had already explained myself, let me rephrase that. if i install this DHCP tool as a service like you said, will i still be able to have this Service start automaticcaly only when the ping fails using the powershell script i have above?

Comment: the question makes sense... just not to you, thanks for trying to help tho :)

Comment: Based on my experience this question sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, u can use an app called Auto-it where u Send a mouse click to a specific button in the Window.
it's explained here in details on the Autoit website

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm