# Run remote exe while bypassing or selecting options

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a remote exe. However whenever I do, this popup keeps showing up with two options, "reset" or "cancel". I want to select the reset button. Is this possible? This is the code I have so far.

```
  Start-Process -Filepath "C:\Programs\Remote.exe" -Wait -Silent 
  ## Not Working Start-Process -Filepath "C:\Programs\Remote.exe" -Wait -Silent -Confirm:$False 
  Echo Y | ##
```

Comment: There is no standard way to select buttons via flags, so it would depend on why you're getting the popup. It's janky, but if you are lucky and the popup window takes focus, then you might be able to use `SendKeys()` to hit reset (maybe ALT+R `'%R'`?) like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66662784/7411885 . You probably won't be able to use `-Wait` if the shell is waiting on that popup

Answer (score 0):

If remote.exe is a console app, you *might* be able to get away with using `Start-Process -RedirectStandardInput`

```
'Y' | Set-Content .\StandardInput.txt
Start-Process -Filepath "C:\Programs\Remote.exe" -Wait -RedirectStandardInput .\StandardInput.txt
```